# GIS Equipment for 911 Call Center

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps

I am the GIS administrator for a 911 call center. Currently we use ArcGIS for our mapping, and my director recently told me that I have a budget every year to purchase GIS/GPS equipment or training. I am looking to for useful equipment that would assist in collecting street or address data, or really anything that would assist mapping for a 911 center. Would anyone on here have any kind of experience with something like that?

Comment: How Accurate? Are we talking Total Station (less than 1cm error). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_station

Comment: Where are you located?  Have you gotten in contact with, assuming they exist, your local city or county GIS staff?  They may very well have some of what you are looking for, and collaboration could save effort and improve the product for both parties.

Comment: It's really hard to offer any specific suggestions without knowing a lot more about what you currently do, what data you have, how you use it, what processes you apply things to, what scale (area of coverage) etc. As mentioned, you're unlikely to need survey grade equipment, and I would think much of what you do would be verification or specific needs that aren't covered by other data sources. Do you (generic, applying to call center) collect everything yourself or do you get base data, like roads and address points, from other sources? How many agencies do you field calls for?

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow GIS-911 professional, if you are looking to maintain the address data, do GIS to MSAG compares, etc... you may also want to look at some of the ArcGIS extensions out there offered by various 911 software companies.  These types of tools can be rather helpful because they can expedite/automate certain parts of workflows, they have significant data quality assessments (ex: identify structures on the wrong road block, overlapping road segment address ranges, etc...) and they generally have workflows that allow for you to directly compare the MSAG and your GIS data (this comparison will be critical before moving to NG911). I don't represent any of these companies or anything, but the 3 such products I know about are 911 Datamaster's [Spatial Station](http://www.911datamaster.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=219&Itemid=114), Intrado's [MapSAG](http://www.intrado.com/solutions/GIS), and Geo-Comm's [Data Management System](http://www.geo-comm.com/geolynx/dms/).

If you already have these tools or you don't feel they're as relevant to you, then also consider looking at various GIS-911 specific training opportunities that may be available in your area.  I don't know where you are located, but I know Texas for example has a state-wide GIS-911 User Group that meets quarterly throughout the state to discuss various issues specific to our industry's needs.  Consider contacting your state's 911 agency to check if they know of any relevant meetings/trainings (or if they have other relevant suggestions, though be careful not to hint to any state agency that you have extra money you're just looking at finding a way to spend).

As far as GPS equipment, honestly I wouldn't spend too much money on anything like that because you don't really need survey grade accuracy or anything in most cases.  At least in my experience, especially in rural areas where parcel, city planning, etc... data isn't already available, any field collection will likely be to collect or validate address/structure point data.  Therefore, all you will really need is something to drive down the road with and take a point at each driveway to record the numbers for the house.  Then import those points into ArcMap and actually do the editing there (that's a lot easier than trying to edit the data in the field on a tiny little screen - I've tried).

Anyway, those are a couple of thoughts off the top of my head, but if you want to discuss the matter further, feel free to let me know in a comment and I'd be happy to discuss more of what my office uses and such as that.

Answer (score 0):

A company near where I live specializes in this type of stuff. I do not represent them or have any involvment but only know about them through conferences. They are called Bradshaw Consulting Services.  They seem to have a pretty good client base and they build software for emergency routing called Mobile Area Routing and Vehicle Location Information System™ (MARVLIS). http://www.bcs-gis.com/